# No Appearance panel is shown

Tags: pages

I am completely new in WordPress. I must change visual appearance of some pages, but in admin panel doesn't shown appearance panel. To be a more concrete, i want to change navigation menu, to add some links. My WordPress version is 3.9.5. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: With the info given in your question it is impossible to understand your issue and there for even more impossible to help you. Please file an [edit] and describe your **exact** problem in detail. :-)

Comment: now is this descriptive ?

Comment: Can you post the Screenshot and let us know more about the issue? Appearance panel can't just go away as it is. Are you working on fresh install?

Comment: did u put any new theme?

Comment: no i has not any.

Comment: Those screenshots aren't WordPress, they're your hosting control panel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are accessing your hosting server panel. There is no way you will find `Appearance` tab there.
Go to this URL: `http://yourdomain.com/wp-admin` to access your WordPress Dashboard. You can view the `Appearance` section there.